Heat equation in 1D with Robin conditions
I am tasked with analytically solving the boundary value problem as follows: the 1D heat equation for temperature $T \equiv T(x,t)$ in a solid extending from $x = 0$ to $x = L$ and located in air at temperature $T_0$.
$$\frac{dT}{dt} = \alpha \cdot \frac{d^2T}{dx^2} \quad ,$$
where $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity. My boundary conditions are as follows:
$$- k \frac{dT}{dx} = q_{in} \qquad \text{at} \enspace x = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$-k \frac{dT}{dx} = hT \qquad \text{at} \enspace x=L \tag{2}$$
$$T(x,t=0) = 0 \tag{3}$$
where $k$ is the thermal conductivity and $q_{in}$ is a (constant) heat flux entering the solid and where $h$ is the convection coefficient (constant) between the solid and air. Note: Here $T = T' - T_0$ where $T'$ is the surface temperature of the solid (this choice is made to simplify calculations).
I have considered the method of superposition to solve this problem. Thus, I can express $T(x,t) = T_{stationary}(x) + T^*(x,t)$.
For $T_{stationary}(x)$, we will try to find a stationary solution to the heat equation that respects the boundary conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ in $T_{stationary}(x)$. You can find my resolution in the attached document "solution_stationary".
According to the principle of superposition, to find $T^*(x,t)$ I must find a non-stationary solution to the heat equation that respects the boundary conditions $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$. But the problem is that I am unable to find my $\lambda_n$ in the calculation of the analytic solution of $T^*(x,t)$ and I do not see how to find $b_n'$. Do you have any ideas?


I have difficulties reading your handwriting, but I have the feeling that there is something wrong with the problem statement or your approach. This feeling is reasoned by the following: Your calculation yields the stationary temperature
$$T_{stat}(x) = A\cdot x + B$$
and the temperature $T^*$
$$T^*(x,t) = e^{-\alpha \lambda^2 t} \Big( a \sin(\lambda x) + b \cos (\lambda x) \Big)$$
The stationary temperature $T_{stat}$ must satisfy the boundary condition at $x=0$:
$$q_{in} = -k \frac{dT_{stat}}{dx}(0,t) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \boxed{-k A = q_{in}}$$
Now consider $T = T_{stat} + T^*$, then the same boundary conditions requires ($T$ must adhere to the same boundary condition, otherwise $T$ is no solution to your problem as stated)
$$ q_{in} = -k \frac{dT}{dx}(0,t) = -k \Big( \frac{dT_{stat}}{dx}(0)   + \frac{dT^*}{dx}(0,t)  \Big) = -k \Big( A + \lambda a e^{-\alpha \lambda^2t} \Big) = q_{in} - k\lambda a e^{-\alpha \lambda^2t}$$
and so $\boxed{a = 0}$ or $\lambda=0$. Note, however, that since the initial condition $T(x,t=0) = 0$ is provided, one also has $\tfrac{dT}{dx}(x,t=0) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,L]$ and so
$$0 = \frac{dT}{dx}(0,0) = \frac{dT_{stat}}{dx}(0)  + \frac{dT^*}{dx}(0,0) = A$$
and therefore $\boxed{A=0}$. But then $q_{in} = 0$ which would mean that no heat flux enters the solid and so it should stay at its initial temperature $T = T_0$. I guess such a result is not intended in this problem.

You are right. In fact, here is the context of what I am trying to do. I would like to model how the solid will react when exposed to a heat flux $q_{in}$ that starts at $T = 0^+$ and stops after $t = 7200[s]$. And after this time the heat flux in x = 0 is equal to 0. So, I am interested in the transient response. I am attaching a finite element simulation of the problem where the solid is made of refractory brick.
I am interested in this because I would like to perform a material selection to achieve significant heat storage without experiencing excessive temperature rise at $x = L$. That's why I would like to have an analytical solution of the temperature field in the solid based on the material properties of the solid to see which properties will influence it and to what extent (first order, second order, etc.). Do you have any idea on how to proceed?


Just to clarify: The heat flux $q_{in}$ is not constant (as opposed to statement in the initial question) but rather a function of time? Is it continuous or do you want to model the case where the heat flux is constant until $t = 7200 , \mathrm{s}$ is reached and then turn it off abruptly? P.S. I think it is more appropriate to edit your question instead of adding detail as an answer.

q_in is constant and when t = 7200[s] the flux is turned off.

I have the impression that your boundary conditions applied to $T^*$ are not correct. The non-homogeneous condition at $0$ is already taken into account in the permanent solution. So you have to impose $(\frac{\partial{T^*}}{\partial{x}})_{x=0}=0$.
Thus, we will have the desired condition for the solution:
$(\frac{\partial{T_{stationnary} + T^*}}{\partial{x}})_{x=0}=(\frac{\partial{T_{stationnary}}}{\partial{x}})_{x=0}+(\frac{\partial{T^*}}{\partial{x}})_{x=0}=q_{int}$.

This is just a reformulation of my answer below and - as can be seen therein - implies that $q_{in} = 0$.

Perhaps I misunderstood your answer? But what I indicate does not lead to having  $q_{int}=0$

You are right. I corrected it and I found a solution to my problem. Thank you !
